# When debugging project XYZ a page from ABC will pop up with an exception?

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, .net

Not sure how much sense that title makes, but the issue that I am running into is that when I begin debugging a project (XYZ) a page from a completely different project (ABC), that is in a different solution will pop up when it hits an exception.

These are two totally different projects that contain custom code that is being run against the same SharePoint instance.  I took a screen shot of what is going on:

[image]

The tab that is selected has popped up and thrown a null reference exception, but if you look in my solution explorer you will see that this file does not exist there.  Why would something like this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when debugging Visual Studio will stop on [User-Unhandled Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/038tzxdw%28v=vs.80%29)

Comment: I would add Ctrl-Alt-E normally brings up the dialog for controlling what exceptions Visual Studio breaks on, and in what conditions. I find breaking on *any* thrown exception can be useful during development/debugging.